# How to limit the Activation bar so that I can use the exp () function for type <T>?

Tags: rust

I am trying to make a sigmoid function that works with the numbers f32 and f64.
This code gets an error - no method named `exp` found for type`& T` in the current scope.
I think I know why this happens, and I want to explain to the compiler that the numbers will be F32 and F64, but I don’t know how. Sorry for my English .

```
pub trait Activation<T> {
  fn compute(&self,input:&Vec<T>) -> Vec<T>;
}

pub struct Sigmoid {}
  impl Sigmoid {
    pub fn new() -> Sigmoid {
      Sigmoid{}
    }
  }

  impl<T> Activation<T> for Sigmoid {
  fn compute(&self, input: &Vec<T>) -> Vec<> {
    let mut out:Vec<T> = vec![];
      for (i,v) in input.iter().enumerate() {
        let mut z =  *v.exp() ;
        out.push(z);
      }
    out
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you could use the num_traits crate:

```
use num_traits::float::Float;

pub trait Activation<T: Float> {
    fn compute(&self, input: &Vec<T>) -> Vec<T>;
}

pub struct Sigmoid {}
impl Sigmoid {
    pub fn new() -> Sigmoid {
        Sigmoid {}
    }
}

impl<T> Activation<T> for Sigmoid
    where T: Float {

    fn compute(&self, input: &Vec<T>) -> Vec<T> {
        let mut out: Vec<T> = vec![];
        for (_, v) in input.iter().enumerate() {
            let z = v.exp();
            out.push(z);
        }

        out
    }
}
```

You can also implement this without the num crate, but its a tad ugly:

```
pub trait LocalFloat {
    fn exp(self) -> Self;
}

impl LocalFloat for f32 {
    fn exp(self) -> Self {
        f32::exp(self)
    }
}

impl LocalFloat for f64 {
    fn exp(self) -> Self {
        f64::exp(self)
    }
}

pub trait Activation<T: LocalFloat> {
    fn compute(&self, input: &Vec<T>) -> Vec<T>;
}

pub struct Sigmoid {}
impl Sigmoid {
    pub fn new() -> Sigmoid {
        Sigmoid {}
    }
}

impl<T> Activation<T> for Sigmoid
    where T: LocalFloat + Copy {

    fn compute(&self, input: &Vec<T>) -> Vec<T> {
        let mut out: Vec<T> = vec![];
        for (_, v) in input.iter().enumerate() {
            let z = v.exp();
            out.push(z);
        }

        out
    }
}
```